# c++ big vector in function called multiple times

Tags: c++, performance, function, vector, software-quality

I have a function that creates a big vector for its internal work. Say we need also to call this function many times. What's the best way to handle the memory creation/destruction of the vector (factors are performance, Quality of Code..)

Method 1:

```
void f(int n) {
    vector<int> v(n);
 }

 int main() {
     for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) f(10000000);
 }
```

Method 2:

```
void f(int n) {
    static vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(99999999); // say this is the maximum possible size

    v.resize(n);
}

 int main() {
     for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) f(10000000);
 }
```

Method 2 is definitely faster than Method 1, but it looks ugly.
What would be the best approach

Comment: It is interesting, it seems what ever is causing the performance increase is really whats going on in the `vector<int> v(n);` to slow it down. At least what I think. Possibly 2 reserve calls being forced in first method.

Comment: Also the source to stl vector will be compiler specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn the function into a class with an `operator()`.

```
class f_class {

   std::vector<int> v;

public:

   f_class()
   {
        v.reserve(99999999);
   }

   void operator()(int n)
   {
        v.resize(n);
        // Whatever the original f() did
   }
};

int main() {

     f_class f;

     for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) f(i);
}
```

Comment: Still in this solution, the caller (here main()) must be aware that class_f uses a vector, if we did class_f()(i) in each iteration we would fall in the same problem again. That means the outside must know a bit about the implementation of class_f which doesn't fit well with OOP principles (encapsulation, abstraction)

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, your vector size is same so why not create only one vector?

```
  using namespace std;
    void f(vector<int>& v) {
        // Do something with vector
    }
    int main() {

        int n = 10000000;
        vector<int> v(n);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
            f(v);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v.reserve() //deals with capacity.
v.resize(n) //deals with size.
```

In Method 2, what the static vector is experiencing, is just changing the size, however, the reserved space is more than than the size, therefore there is no change in the capacity, and when you are iterating through the loop it just increases by one. Therefore, the size just gets increased by one every time. The capacity has no change. *Usually* if resize is called on an empty vector of int, the vector elements at that resize range would be initialized to 0.

On Method 1, the vector is being created with a size of n, but with the most proximate n<2^k integer value as a capacity (for example if n=100, then capacity 128, when n=200, capacity 256, and so on). Also, when you are calling the method one, you are creating and destroying each time the function goes out of scope. It is to note that the vector is empty, as it does not have any values.

In Method 2, the vector is static and remains.

You *may* want to read:

[Reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/)

[Capacity](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/capacity/)

Also, if you are having the vector reserve memory, and assuming you *may* not be bothered by the amount of memory, a pre-allocation of memory, with constant insertions by amortized analysis would have a Big-O(1), for each operation.